# Creating a dictionary using 2 lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 lists:

```
name = ["Stirling","Lana","Cyril","Pam","Ray","Cheryl"]

alias =["Duchess","Truckasaurus","Chet","Cookie Monster","Gilles de Rais","Cherlene"]
```

I need to create a dictionary such that the name is the key and alias is the value, in this particular way:

```
Stirling : Duchess
```

Also I have to use the for loop to do so.

Comment: Perhaps `my_dict = dict(zip(name, alias))`, but please explain why  you must use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply `zip` them.

```
name = ["Stirling","Lana","Cyril","Pam","Ray","Cheryl"]

alias =["Duchess","Truckasaurus","Chet","Cookie Monster","Gilles de Rais","Cherlene"]

my_dict = dict(zip(name, alias))
```

Comment: Thats right but what if I have to make use of a for statement for eg:

for i in range(0,len(name)):
    #Add pairs to the dictionary from the lists


for Loop through sorted dictionary:
    #Print item and value